# Combining Maps using containers.map in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am reading about the 'containers.map' class on the Mathworks website (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.iskey.html) and I am confused about combining maps.

Consider the following example:

```
keySet =   {'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'};
valueSet = [327.2, 368.2, 197.6, 178.4];
mapObj = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet)
```

and checking for membership by typing the following:

```
keySet = {'Apr','May','Jun'};
tf = isKey(mapObj,keySet)
```

results in:

```
tf =

     1     0     0
```

Now if we want to combine two maps, we simply concatenate as follows:

```
keySet   = {'Jun','Jul','Aug'};
valueSet = [ 69.9, 32.3, 37.3];
newMap = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet);

mapObj = [mapObj; newMap];
```

and, similarly, to test membership (of a different set) we can write:

```
keySet = {'Jan','May','Aug','Dec'};
tf = isKey(mapObj,keySet)
```

and obtain:

```
tf =

      1   0   1   0
```

**Question**: Now, as far as I understand, containers.map uses hash functions. Why can we construct the map for newMap independently of mapObj -- wouldn't this result in potential collisions when we look up keys?

Comment: Do you mean if a key is present in both the old and new map?

Comment: @Jørgen Yes, I think so, as in an element from the new keySet gets hashed to a quantity that is already taken by one of the elements from the original keySet.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that. The hashing algorithms are typically very good at getting unique values, and even collisions can easily be handled.